# Ошибка Exception unhandled

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста исправить оишбку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот весь код, c++. итератор за пределы массива не выходит

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    short n, mx = -101, f = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int* mass = new int[n];
    int mxindexes[100];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
        if (mass[i] > mx)
        {
            mx = mass[i];

        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[i] == mx)
        {
            mxindexes[f] = i;
            f++;
        }
    }
    for (int L = f; L >0; L--)
    {
        for (int i = mxindexes[L]; i <n; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = mass[i+1];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n-f+1; i++)
    {
        mass[i] = mx;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: Массивы в С++ начинаются с 0 и заканчиваются на n-1

Comment: И что ? Хоть с 20 пусть начинается, это проблему не должно вызывать

Answer (score 4):

Как это "итератор за пределы массива не выходит"?

А тут?

```
int* mass = new int[n];

.....

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (mass[i] == mx)
    {
```

Да и вы гарантируете, что дальше `f` не станет равным 100? Да и дальше натыкано много чего...

Посмотрите отладчиком, чему равны ваши значения индексов.

Вы помните (или нет?), что нумерация массивов в С++ начинается с нуля?

Или вот (то самое место, куда вы по случайности UB таки добрались...):

```
        mxindexes[f] = i;
        f++;
    }
}
```

Итак, последний `f` - **за пределами** `mxindexes`. А тут вы

```
for (int L = f; L >0; L--)
{
    for (int i = mxindexes[L]; i <n; i++)
```

начинаете работать с **неинициализированным** значением в `mxindexes[L]` (при первой итерации `L` равно `f`, т.е. за пределами инициализированной части...)

Comment: Да там в каждом цикле такое %)

Comment: нет таких входных данных, из-за которых ф ставал бы равным или больше 100. И какая разница как нумеровать массив. в данном случае массив заполняю от 1 до n включительно, это то же самое, что от 0 до n-1

Comment: А с неинициализированным элементом массива вы тоже не работаете? А этот шедевр - *массив заполняю от 1 до n включительно, это то же самое, что от 0 до n-1* - это вообще феерично. Улица. Дома от 1 до 10. Вы рассылаете письма, указываете в адресах дома с 2 по 11 - и считаете, что это то же самое, что и с 1 по 10? :) Ну укажите с 21 по 30 - авось так еще лучше дойдет :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int* mass = new int[n];
```

Запомним, под `mass` выделено `n` элементов (с индексами от `0` до `n-1`).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    ...
    mass[i];
    ...
}
```

На последнем проходе будет `i = n`, значит будет обращение к `mass[n]`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    ...
    mass[i+1];
    ...
}
```

На последнем проходе будет `i = n - 1`, значит будет обращение к `mass[n]`.

И так по всем циклам практически.

Answer (score 0):

Элементы массива в C++ (и многих других языках) нумеруются с нуля. Тут, например,

```
int n = 5;
int* mass = new int[n];
```

Я выделил память под массив из 5 интов, НО первый элемент в нем будет иметь индекс `0`, а последний `4 (n-1)` Это необходимо учитывать. Вы в комментариях писали:

> И какая разница как нумеровать массив. в данном случае массив заполняю
> от 1 до n включительно, это то же самое, что от 0 до n-1

Не тоже самое ни разу. Вы в случае такого цикла

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{

if (mass [i] == mx){// код... }
}
```

Говорите машине:

> Организуй мне, пожалуйста, цикл, и в нем проверь элементы массива, начиная с элемента
> **С ИНДЕКСОМ 1** (То есть **второго**) в массиве (То есть первый **НЕ** проверяй) До элемента с **ИНДЕКСОМ** `n` Включительно. (То есть **ШЕСТОГО** (n+1) по порядку).

Компилятор такой:

> Хозяин, Вы выделили память только под `n` элементов, а `n+1` элемента не существует и Вы обращаетесь к чужой памяти. Остановитесь и подумайте.

Компилятор вообще хороший парень, его надо слушать.

Comment: В данном случае - точности ради - компилятор ничего не говорит. Он компилирует - синтаксис-то верный... Эти проблемы выявляются уже не на уровне компиляции, а при выполнении...